# QTCreator Giving ListWidgetItems Multiple Attributes

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qcheckbox, qspinbox, qlistwidgetitem

So I'm using QTCreator to create a GUI for a project. I'm reading items from a file, and then those items are imported into a ListWidget with checkboxes next to each item. I was wondering if it's possible to have the checkbox along with a spin box or some other sort of numeric attribute tied to each item, and if so could you explain how?
Edit: If anyone know hows to add any of the editable text boxes instead that'd actually work even better.
This is what I'm currently doing to open/read the file:

```
QFile ingFile("/root/Desktop/file.txt");
ingFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream in(&ingFile);
QStringList inglist;
QString line = in.readLine();
while(!line.isNull()){
    inglist.append(line);
    line = in.readLine();
}
QStringListIterator it(inglist);
while(it.hasNext()){
    QListWidgetItem *listitem = new QListWidgetItem(it.next());
    listitem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    ui->ingList->addItem(listitem);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `QTableView` with `QStandardItemModel` and a subclass of `QStyledItemDelegate`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov How would I go about doing this? I'm really not that familiar with QT, definitely still learning.

Comment: Check out [Model/View Tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) and [Spin Box Delegate Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html).